# Luke - No valid directory at the current location

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am currently working on indexing large text files. I am using Apache Lucene 4.6.1 to index files and for search options. I am using Luke4.6 jar to test the indexes. I Downloaded the jar from [HERE](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/4.6.0). But I am getting error "INVALID DIRECTORY"

Error Message :

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/home/hduser/prayaas/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@74c90b3a: files: [_8.cfe, _0.cfs, _7.cfs, _1.si, _2.cfs, _a.fdx, _4.cfs, _8.cfs, _8.si, _6.cfs, _2.si, _9.si, _a.fdt, _1.cfe, _3.si, _1.cfs, _7.cfe, _3.cfe, _5.si, _5.cfs, _5.cfe, _4.cfe, _0.si, _9.cfs, _6.si, _6.cfe, _9.cfe, _0.cfe, _2.cfe, _4.si, _3.cfs, _7.si]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:801)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400)
    at org.getopt.luke.Luke.openIndex(Luke.java:868)
    at org.getopt.luke.Luke.openOk(Luke.java:678)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at thinlet.Thinlet.invokeImpl(Thinlet.java:4579)
    at thinlet.Thinlet.invoke(Thinlet.java:4546)
    at thinlet.Thinlet.handleMouseEvent(Thinlet.java:3937)
    at thinlet.Thinlet.processEvent(Thinlet.java:2917)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

My Code :

```
public class LuceneTest 
{
public static final String INDEX_DIR_PATH = "/home/hduser/prayaas/index";
public static final String FILES_DIR_PATH = "/home/hduser/prayaas/input";
private IndexWriter writer;


public void readFile()
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/hduser/prayaas/test.txt")));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] fields = line.split("\t");
            for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
                System.out.print(i+" "+fields[i]+"\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
        br.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initWriter() /* To Initialize IndexWriter class */
{
    try 
    {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIR_PATH));
        Analyzer a    = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
        writer        = new IndexWriter(dir, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, a).setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE)); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error in Creating Index Writer. Please specify the folder Correctly for storing index");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void indexFile(File file)
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line;
        while( (line=br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] fields     = line.split("\t");
            String[] fieldNames = {"userid","usertype","age","gender","country","pva","sqa","minspent","visits"};
            Document doc = new Document();

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                if(i != 2)
                    doc.add(new StringField(fieldNames[i], fields[i],Store.YES));
                else
                    doc.add(new IntField(fieldNames[i], Integer.parseInt(fields[i]),Store.YES));

            for(int i=7;i<=8;i++)
                doc.add(new IntField(fieldNames[i], Integer.parseInt(fields[i]),Store.YES));

            for(int i=5;i<7;i++)
                if(fields.length > 0)
                {
                    String[] special = fields[i].split("\\|");

                    for(int j=0;j<special.length;j++)
                    {
                        String[] temp = special[j].split(";");
                        if(temp.length > 1)
                        {
                            doc.add(new StringField(fieldNames[i], temp[0],Store.YES));
                            doc.add(new IntField(temp[0], Integer.parseInt(temp[1]),Store.YES));
                        }
                    }
                }

            writer.addDocument(doc);

        }

        br.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void indexDirectory(String path)
{
    File dataDir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dataDir.listFiles();

    for(File file : files)
    {
        if( file.isDirectory() )
            indexDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath());
        else
            indexFile(file);
    }
}
public void searchIndex()
{
    //IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(new File(INDEX_DIR_PATH));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LuceneTest lt = new LuceneTest();
    lt.initWriter();
    lt.indexDirectory(FILES_DIR_PATH);
    System.out.println("Success");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting the luke release corresponding to your Lucene version: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/4.6.1

Or even better, get the latest release, that is just out:

https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Just a small bug in my code.

> I didn't close the **IndexWriter object**